# How to kill an application that locks/freezes the system when that app does not show in System Monitor

Tags: 14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on a Dell OptiPlex GX520, 80GB HDD.
I started seeing messages about insufficient space in the boot partition so I ran AutoClean. When I rebooted the system, "Bleachbit" launched.  Its dialog box shows in the upper, left corner of the display and I am unable to dismiss it.  The only thing I can do is select Preview or Delete and choose the options I want.  Whatever I select, the app appears to begin working, then the screen goes dim and they system seems to freeze.  I cannot do anything at that point except reboot the computer.  When I do, the same thing occurs.

I have attempted to boot from CD, but get a message telling me that the boot device is not present, even though that device shows in BIOS and is selected as the primary device.

Note that the drive is encrypted and I have to provide the key before the system will complete the boot process.

Can you assist?

Respectfully,

Fergie

---

Thanks for the responses folks.  I have tried to launch a terminal but no joy.  The Ctl+Alt+T sequence has no effect.  I do not see a terminal window on the screen.  The only thing  that gets a response from the system is Ctl+Alt+Del, which brings up system monitor.  I have tried booting from the CD from which I originally installed Ubuntu, but keep getting the error "The selected boot device is not available".

Comment: you could try killing the process, or you could just boot in, log into a TTY terminal and purge the application completely (if this is an option).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the quickest way is to use the terminal, there you just need to type

```
ps -aux | grep 'bleachbit'
```

and the output will be a list of all the processes related to *bleachbit* (except for the last one, which is the search for the program using the `grep` command above). Of each row of the output, the second column is the **pid** of the application (or a secondary process launched by it).

Then, again in the terminal, type

```
kill pid1 pid2 pid2
```

where `pid1`, etc stand for all the pids the output of the first command showed.

In case your system freezes before you can launch a terminal, you can press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` to go to a `tty` (basically, just another terminal). Type your login info and you'll get a full-working terminal where you can do all of the above. In case you want to exit from this `tty` press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F7`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy with Force quit applet.

[image: not picture from mysetup]

I'm using Ubuntu Mate where it is available by default ...(picture is from internet)

In my case there is always some clickable residue of misbehaving application (frozen window in most cases) and this little applet always did the trick!

Basically it's `kill` command...